# how to convert string to date in big query

Tags: google-bigquery

tried with below query 
select parse_date("sting_date", %y-%m-%d) form [project_id:dataset.table]

input value 
string value = 20150518
expected output 
date value = 2015-05-18

Tried to parse_date("sting date", %y-%m-%d) in selection query not worked

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an uppercase Y and flip arguments:

```
SELECT
  PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', '20180805') AS date
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that should be parse_date("%y%m%d", sting_date)

see:[parse date](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#parse_date)